# How to insert Pojo objects into Oracle DB using JdbcTemplate without writing SQL queries?

Tags: java, mongodb, oracle, spring-boot

I am working on  feature for my project where I need to migrate data from Mongo to Oracle DB.
I am able to read the data from Mongo and create pojo objects which has camel case field names (example: firstName, lastName, jobTitle etc)

To store the same data on the Oracle side, I have created tables already with custom DDLs whose column names for the same data would look like - FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, JOB_TITLE etc.

I have many collections on Mongo to be copied to Oracle similarly. Each of those collections have their own specific column/field names. So, it would be a really hard thing to write SQL insert queries in my code base to add data to Oracle DBs.

Is there a way I could use in Springboot to just map these field names from Mongo to their respective column names and insert the data using the Pojo Objects themselves, given I know which table needs the insert all the time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with Spring Boot Data JPA library instead of JDBC. You will define Entity classes similar to your POJO. Or even reuse it. Then define JpaRepository interfaces and call it's save methods to persist in the database.